# Removing different types of double quotes from string?

Tags: python, string, subset, quotes

I have a list of names that has sizes in inches in it. Such as:

> Asus VP248QG 24''
>
> BenQ XYZ123456 32"

As you can see first name has double single-quote sign for inches while second name has normal double-quote sign.

I have this code to remove these sizes, because I do not need them:

```
def monitor_fix(s):
    if ('"' in s):
        return re.sub(r'\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)"\s*$', '', str(s))
    if ("''" in s):
        return re.sub(r"\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)''\s*$", '', str(s))
```

But it only removes ordinary double-quote sign, not the double single-quote sign. How to deal with this?

Comment: How about `re.sub(r'\'|\"','',your_text)`?

Comment: Do you just want to remove all occurrences of `"` and `''`? Regex seems like overkill.

Comment: assign result back to `s` and use `return` after last `if`

Comment: @DanielRoseman I want to remove all occurrences of any number and quote sign between one space and the quote sign. So I am trying to remove sizes and inch sign completely.

Comment: you can simply with one regex, ['"]+ (there is single quote and double) use also your main regex to check digits

Comment: @furas I'm doing this when call my function like monitor_name = monitor_fix(monitor_name)

Comment: I mean assign `s = re.sub()` - this way it will check both `if`. Now it exits function  after removing double qoutes and it doesn't check double single qoutes

Comment: It does not remove double single-quotes even if I change the order of if statements, so problem is not here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the sizes are always well separated with spaces, we can simply remove the "word" that contains quotes. Bonus point because the size can be anywhere in the string too.

```
products = ["Asus VP248QG 24'' silver", 'BenQ XYZ123456 32"']

for n, product in enumerate(products):

    product_without_size = ""
    for word in product.split(" "):
        if not("''" in word or '"' in word):   # If the current word is not a size,
            product_without_size += word + " " # add it to the product name (else skip it).
    products[n] = product_without_size.rstrip(" ")

print(products) # ['Asus VP248QG silver', 'BenQ XYZ123456']
```

Using the format of your original post, it would look like this:

```
def monitor_fix(product):

    product_without_size = ""
    for word in product.split(" "):
        if not("''" in word or '"' in word):   # If the current word is not a size,
            product_without_size += word + " " # add it to the product name (else skip it).
    return product_without_size.rstrip(" ")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply remove the last 4 - 5 symbols with string[:]

```
list = ["Asus VP248QG 24''", 'BenQ XYZ123456 32"']

for i in range(len(list)):
    if "''" in list[i]:
        list[i] = list[i][:-5]
    if '"' in list[i]:
         list[i] = list[i][:-4]
    print(list[i])
```